# How to backup data on debian vps to dropbox?

Tags: backup, debian, dropbox, vps

I have really simple private VPS with some webpages and music server. I want to backup some configs and some scripts to dropbox or similar service. Server has no gui (except simple ssh X forwarding, which is neither convenient for constant usage and does not provide full desktop) everything is controlled through ssh.

So my question would is it possible to setup dropbox client for command line use? How? Is there any alternatives for dropbox, which would have command line clients?

Also is it possible to incorporate backup into script for cron job?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. There actually is [an official Dropbox guide](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/using-the-official-dropbox-command-line-interface-cli) which will guide you through everything.

Comment: Dead link - not a surprise after nine years I suppose.

Comment: @WiseOldDuck Very true, but there is a new guide, easy to find after all: https://help.dropbox.com/installs/linux-commands

Comment: Missing a lot of detail on that last link. Tells you how to get Dropbox Desktop installed, and gives cli commands, but only for ordinary Dropbox Folder sync and related functions. Nothing that would enable you to effectively back up anything on a server besides the dedicated Dropbox Folder.